# Codename One MapContainer.addDragFinishedListener() does not receive updates

Tags: codenameone

Codename One, Adding a `DragFinishedListener` to the `MapContainer` class does not receive any events. Adding `MapListener` works as expected.

```
    mapContainer.addDragFinishedListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Don't see this");               
        }
    });


    mapContainer.addMapListener(new MapListener() {         

        @Override
        public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zoom, Coord center) {
            System.out.println("I see this");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a listener for drag and drop not for pan. If you drag a component e.g. a label onto a map that might be fired but it won't be fired for standard panning.

The best way is the map listener but you can also use pointer drag events and pointer release events.

Comment: Thx for reply. The mapContainer.addPointerDraggedListener(), mapContainer.addPointerReleasedListener() and mapContainer.addPointerPressedListener() don't do anything for standard panning.

Comment: I need to know once the map has stopped moving so I can draw markers for the new area. Only addMaplistener() works but it receives events during a drag which in my case causes unnecessary calls. Any other ideas ? Don't really want to add a refresh button to populate the screen. Thx

Comment: Use pointerRelease events to detect that, use the map listener to detect panning and pointer release to detect that panning stopped.